# Link paths in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, path

I'm starting on Rails now I have some problem that I can't get through, here's an example:

I have a table called Product which have name, photo, etc., and a table called review, which have a name and a `product_id`. Each product can have many reviews and each review only have one product. When I select a product on the index page it directs me to the Show view, I put this link there `<%= link_to 'Reviews', review_path(@product)%>` and it redirects me to `/reviews/1`, and it shows me only one review from the it, and I'm trying to show every review from the product 1.

I have the following code to try catch all the review's from the product. How can I put in the `@review` only the reviews with the `product_id=1`?

```
def show_prod
  @review = Review.find(params[:product_id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @review }
  end
end
```

---

Thanks a lot but i still get the same error

You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.each

It's from the review index page when i write all the reviews from a product. Its seem's like @reviews from the controller isn't getting any product and the object is nil..

Thanks for any help

Comment: Questions that are answerable only by people who use Ruby on Rails should be tagged "ruby-on-rails" rather than "ruby". If you're not sure if your question is about Ruby on Rails or just about Ruby, tag it with both and someone will remove the tag that doesn't apply.

Answer (score 1):

First, created a reviews resource nested under products in routes.rb

```
resources :products do
  resources :reviews
end
```

Link to it with the product.

```
link_to "Reviews", product_reviews_path(@product)
```

Then scope the reviews controller to the product, like this:

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :load_product

  def index
    @reviews = @product.reviews
  end

  def show
    @review = @product.reviews.find(params[:id])
  end

  protected

  def load_product
    @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but i still get the same error

You have a nil object when you didn't expect it! You might have expected an instance of Array. The error occurred while evaluating nil.each

It's from the review index page when i write all the reviews from a product. Its seem's like @reviews from the controller isn't getting any product and the object is nil..

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this tutorial on Rails 3 routing](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources), esp. the section on **Nested Resources**.

My guess is that your resulting path (to get the list of all reviews on that product) will be something like `/product/1/reviews`